# Media queries having no effect

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

This is the code:

```
<style>

h1 {
  color: #007fed;
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  top: 73%;
  width: 100%;
}



body {
    background: url(../dist/img/bg.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    -o-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen
  and (device-width: 320px)
  and (device-height: 640px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        body {
            overflow: scroll !important;
            background: 0 !important;
            background-color: #ccc !important;
        }

}

@media screen
  and (device-width: 360px)
  and (device-height: 640px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        body {
            overflow: scroll !important;
            background: 0 !important;
            background-color: #ccc !important;
        }

}

@media screen
  and (device-width: 320px)
  and (device-height: 480px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        body {
            overflow: scroll !important;
            background: 0 !important;
            background-color: #ccc !important;
        }

}

@media screen
  and (device-width: 768px)
  and (device-height: 1024px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
        body {
            overflow: scroll !important;
            background: 0 !important;
            background-color: #ccc !important;
        }

}


</style>
```

On phone there is some white space at the bottom, the background image is not filling the entire screen so I want to remove it only on phone, also allow scroll on phone as I don't on desktop, but those media queries have no effect, tested on mutiple phones and tablets.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: x` conditions?

Comment: Oh, it actually worked, I thought that may help me detect the phones easily, I was trying to detect for example if it is Galaxy or Iphone